# SQL query search operation with multiple keyword in same table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query as below, where product name is "**Enemy Of The State (Movies, Blu-ray)**" and another product name is "**Samsung Galaxy Note 8 6.3" 64 GB Mobile**". User can search only "**Samsung**", or user can search "**Samsung Note**" or user can search "**Samsung Note 8**" but in all case result should come with proper result. And same for other products.

```
select *
from Product
where Contains(name, '"Enemy*" and "Of*" and "The*"')

select *
from Product
where Contains(name, '"samsung*" and "Note*" and "8*"')
```

I am not getting proper results. Anyone helps me.

Comment: If you are going to use full text search, you need to learn about parameters, such as minimum word length and stop words.

Comment: You could take a look at the `%LIKE` command which way be what you are looking for.

Comment: I can write an answer but it dependes on your needs. Maybe [**LIKE**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can work for you or you must use [FULL TEXT SEARCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) or even a [**custom solution**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Performance+Tuning/87863/)

Answer (score 0):

Below query will return all data from the product table where the word 'samsung' is found.

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE name LIKE '%samsung%'
```

Comment: what is the query for search keyword "Samsung Note 8" in same table having above mentioned product in table.

Comment: `WHERE name LIKE '%Samsung Note 8%'`

Comment: any other option then LIKE?
Because in same product name different then in just above comment. You can see product name is "Samsung Galaxy Note 8 6.3" 64 GB Mobile".
In above like query no result is found.

Comment: You can search for each word/phrase individually.

 `WHERE name LIKE '%samsung%' OR name LIKE '%galaxy%' OR name LIKE '%Samsung Galaxy%'`

Comment: Did you get the expected result with the above suggestion?

Comment: No Sir, I dynamically generate query in SP to get output. Above product name is in table. My requirement is I can search anything randomly, but output will be come, either I search from prefix or post-fix or in between from the product name.

Answer (score -1):

In order to select data where there are a few substrings, you can use the LIKE operator as:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE name LIKE 'Samsung%Note%8%'
```

the % character can be replaced by any string, so you can adapt it as you want.
However, search is based on the order of those substrings, so 'Samsung' has to be the 1st one, 'Note' the second one, ...

Note that if your table contains a lot of data, the associated query may be slow.

Comment: It is doubtful that such an approach will be generally useful because it assumes order is significant - and that the source of the search terms is rational and does not randomly order those search terms. Google doesn't make that assumption and the expectation should be that no one else does.